# GWT: finding the Java Source from the HTML

Tags: java, gwt

I just started working on a huge gwt project and asked myself if there is a smart way to find the gwt java classes while researching the HTML with firebug (or simular).
For example, I've a table somewhere on a html page and need to find the gwt class which generated this table.

I'm using gwt 2.4.0, eclipse 3.7, mostly firefox with firebug and the gwt-development-plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the debugId:

http://ars-codia.raphaelbauer.com/2011/02/when-gwts-debug-ids-come-in-handy.html

You'll need to enable the debug module for that: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/debug/client/package-summary.html

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is finding the table's ID (if it was set) or other attribute and searching through your Java code to see where it was set.

GWT generated code is highly obfuscated, and the variable names are changed to something smaller to save space - so there's no "easy" way to discover the original code from the JS.

Comment: There is no ID set. Thanks for that info. Would be a nice feature for the gwt browser plugin to find the code, maybe someday. Till then I had to go the "hard" way.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the "Output style" of your compiled JavaSript to detailed, then it keeps the varible and class names of your Java project.

However this will make your JS files 100 times bigger and it never helped me debug an application. I actually found all my errors using the debug mode in eclipse! Code which didn't work correct in compiled mode also didn't work in the emulated debug version (when debugging, they are simulation the JavaSript functions with Java over the browser plugin).

[image]

Comment: I will try that compiler option too, but as you say, using the debug mode of eclipse makes probably more sense. Thank you.